# How to sync multiple perforce workspaces

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have multiple workspaces in Perforce, say `w1`, `w2`, `w3`,... all with different mappings that may or may not point to different folders in the same depot(s). I want to write a `.bat` file that syncs them automatically and **in sequence** as not to put stress on the server.

Optimally, I want to start this off automatically and have it first sync w1, after it's done have it sync w2, and so on. Assume I don't have any environment variables set, so if they're necessary, please let me know.

How would go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to set up any P4 environment variables, you could use the [global options](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/o.gopts.html) and do something like this:

```
p4 -u <user> -P <password> -p <port> login
p4 -u <user> -P <password> -p <port> -c <workspace1> sync //path/to/sync/...
p4 -u <user> -P <password> -p <port> -c <workspace2> sync //other/path/...
p4 -u <user> -P <password> -p <port> -c <workspace3> sync //yet/another/path/...
```

If you set up the P4USER, P4PASSWD, and P4PORT P4 environment variables (see the [p4 set](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/set.html) command), then you could clean it up a little to look like this:

```
p4 login
p4 -c <workspace1> sync //path/to/sync/...
p4 -c <workspace2> sync //other/path/...
p4 -c <workspace3> sync //yet/another/path/...
```

Comment: In my case -c <workspace> didn't work. -c<workspace> did (notice no space). It could be because I was using an environment variable. set GLOBAL_OPTIONS="-c sahil" (sahil is my workspace's name). `p4 %GLOBAL_OPTIONS% sync filePath`. Maybe in case of directly using on the command line without environment variable space won't matter.

Comment: In other words  `p4  "-c sahil" sync   filePath` doesn't work, `p4  -c sahil sync   filePath` does. Small gotcha.